# Shrink the Stack Exchange Footer

Tags: script, style

All Stack Exchange sites (except Stack Overflow) have a **giant** footer:
[image: Big footer]

I don't like to have all of that space being taken up on my screen, so I built this user-style:

```css
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Jed Fox
 *
 * (The MIT License)
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
 * a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
 * "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
 * without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
 * distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
 * permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject
 * to the following conditions:
 *
 * - The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
 *   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
 * IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
 * CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
 * TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
 * SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */
#footer-sites {
    display: none !important;
}

#footer #copyright, #footer #svnrev {
    display: inline-block !important;
}

#footer #svnrev::before {
    content: "//";
    margin: 0.25em;
}
```

<sup>try installing Stylish and adding this</sup>

This shrinks the footer:
[image: Small Footer]

The sites are available from the Stack Exchange dropdown at the top-left, and the extra line for the revision was bothering me, so I added it to the same line.

Userscript: <kbd>[install](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/j-f1/4b07b900ea3d78409c80b190099d15f4/raw/6aa942c7f3a20cf04275ea0ebffba86bb1beaa74/shrink-footer.user.js)</kbd> <kbd>[view source](https://gist.github.com/j-f1/4b07b900ea3d78409c80b190099d15f4#file-shrink-footer-user-js)</kbd>
<sup>adapted from [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/6970/34727)</sup>